# How to return Multiple user-group from ParticipantStepChooser in AEM 6.5 workflow

Tags: workflow, aem, aem-6

In AEM workflow, I have a requirement to return multiple user-group from a ParticipantStepChooser implementation class? I have that list of user-group in historyitem of the workflow.
All the reference I got is returning eighter a single user of a single user-group.
I am even not sure whether it is possible to return multiple user-group. Any help is accepted.

Comment: Is the goal to return only a user or a few users from a group, instead of all the users of a single group. Any success?

Comment: @ronnyfm, the requirement in to return multiple group.. We didn't got any success yet, so we need to change our approach ...